# TSQL Result Error

Tags: t-sql

We have a PeopleSoft report running for years without any issues until recently it started producing erroneous results. In order to correct the issue, we had to group the WHERE clause parameters. Please take a look at the screenshot below: 
[Query Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBlCi.jpg)

The query should not retrieve any data at all, given the parameters. The query on the top is the modified one and the one at the bottom is what the report has been running for over 5 years without any errors. Now I'm having to explain to the business stakeholders why it's behaving like that. Any thoughts?

```
-- THIS QUERY EXECUTES FINE AND DISPLAYS EXPECTED RESULT (TOP PANE)
SELECT PRODUCT, HM_RETIRE_FLAG, RETIREMENT_DT  
FROM FSPROD..PS_HM_PRODUCT_AM 
WHERE PRODUCT = '7U3'
   AND (HM_RETIRE_FLAG = 'Y'  OR (HM_RETIRE_FLAG = 'Y' AND RETIREMENT_DT > getdate()))

-- THIS QUERY DISPLAYS A COMPLETELY DIFFERENT RESULT (BOTTOM PANE)
SELECT PRODUCT, HM_RETIRE_FLAG, RETIREMENT_DT  
FROM FSPROD..PS_HM_PRODUCT_AM 
WHERE PRODUCT = '7U3' 
     AND HM_RETIRE_FLAG = 'Y'  OR (HM_RETIRE_FLAG = 'Y' AND RETIREMENT_DT > getdate())
```

Comment: The two queries have different semantics, and has higher precedence than or.

Comment: Read about [precedence opertors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) Both SQL queries has not the same condition.

Comment: The first one is bad anyway. Because 'where x=y or (x=y and z=1)'  does the same as 'where x=y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fairly obvious what the difference is. Those queries are not alike in any way.

The first one uses parentheses for the last part of the where clause whereas the last one doesn't.

This means the first one won't return any records as soon as the product='7U3' returns false and the second one will return records as soon as the last or returns true.

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) on precedence to learn how this works.

Also, if next time you post your queries as text instead of screenshots I would have made the effort to point it out in your code :)

Comment: Yep, I didn't fancy typing out the column names the OP should have provided as text either.

Comment: @Tom V, pardon my noob-like posts. I'm really new to posting on StackOverflow. I'll definitely add the codes in plain text next time. But if you're still interested to show me more in details, they're added in the original post.